# Capturing changes from two columns - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have following table:

```
day              cat    x1    x2
2019-10-25       A      P     Open
2019-10-26       A      P     Close
2019-10-27       A      P     Close
2019-10-28       A      I     Close
2019-10-26       B      P     Close
2019-10-27       B      P     Open
2019-10-28       B      P     Open
```

How can I get rows where either "x1" or "x2" has changed within a category "cat"?

```
day              cat    x1    x2
2019-10-26       A      P     Close
2019-10-28       A      I     Close
2019-10-27       B      P     Open
```

I have found some questions with one column changed, but struggling a bit with categorized table and capturing changes from two columns

Comment: what is the version of `SQL Server` you are using ?

Comment: ```SQL Server``` version - v18.1

Comment: that is the version of the `SQL Server Management Studio`. Not the `SQL Server`. Do a `print @@version` to see

Comment: Oh sorry, ```Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the window function `lag()` on column `x1` and `x2` and compare. What you want is a `OR` condition

```
select  *
from
(
    select  *,
            prev_x1 = lag(x1) over(partition by [cat] order by [day]),
            prev_x2 = lag(x2) over(partition by [cat] order by [day])
    from    your_table t
) d
where   x1  <> prev_x1
or      x2  <> prev_x2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the `LAG` function, you can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a ranking of categories by `day`, then `INNER JOIN` against previous record.

```
;WITH RowNumberByCategory AS
(
    SELECT
        T.day,
        T.cat,
        T.x1,
        T.x2,
        RowNumberByCategory = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.cat ORDER BY T.day ASC)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    RowNumberByCategory AS T
    INNER JOIN RowNumberByCategory AS N ON
        T.cat = N.cat AND
        T.RowNumberByCategory - 1 = N.RowNumberByCategory
WHERE
    T.x1 <> N.x1 OR T.x2 <> N.x2
```

Make sure to check against `NULL` values with `ISNULL` on the `WHERE` if your `x1` or `x2` columns can be `NULL`.